# Lowering the speed of a plot loop to see movements in R (without clicking)

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, sapply

I was wondering how I could lower the speed (i.e., the timing) of the `for()` loop below to allow plot changes to be visible and tangible by human eye in R (without having to click enter and just watching the looping run slowly)?

Here is a piece of R code:

```
for (i in 1:50) {

  plot(rnorm(40))
  readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue")

}
```

Comment: Add `Sys.sleep(1)` instead of `readline`

Comment: You could wrap the loop with `pdf()` to make a slideshow/flipbook... that's what I do.

Comment: @Frank, could you please show me frank?

Comment: You put `pdf(file = some_file_path)` before, and `dev.off()` after. I have an example in 3.2.4.4 here, though you'd need the data.table package and to be careful about what folder you run it in for that http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html#extensions-to-the-data.frame-class The `DT[, {do_stuff}, by=g]` there is just like your for loop ... it just happens to be looping over subsets of a table instead.

Comment: You could use Yihui's [animation](https://github.com/yihui/animation) package to turn them into a GIF or video if you like.

Comment: @alistaire In that light, maybe this is a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174799/how-to-make-execution-pause-sleep-wait-for-x-seconds-in-r/1174826 ?

Comment: @parvinkarimi Oh, here's a better illustration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1395437/

Comment: @Frank, that is really wonderful! Could I instead make png?

Comment: Yes. With a pdf, you could put in on multiple pages, while with a png, you'd fill a folder with images (since pngs don't have pages). In the docs `?png` see the `filename` argument for how to specify a pattern to make file names. (I haven't used it that way myself.)

Comment: @Frank, sure, thank you.

Comment: @Frank, I am trying to get a pdf file in the fashion that you suggested for a fairly large plot. Would the size of the plot be a problem?

Comment: @parvin It might be. Scatterplots render in a costly way, whether in a pdf or in an R window. If you're running into that problem, maybe best to look at the hexbin package or something else that coarsens or smooths a scatter plot. I guess it might be an issue for other plotting types as well, but I'm not very familiar.

Comment: @Frank, can I send you an R file before asking a question, everything works fine except when I want to get a png file for each "i", the png files come out blank?

Comment: Nah, sorry. I'm no graphing guru. I only make graphs a couple times a year and always use pdf, base plotting functions, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pauseLength = 4   # length of pause in seconds

for (i in 1:50) {
    plot(rnorm(40))
    Sys.sleep(pauseLength)
}
```