# How can I trigger plotly hover after a certain duration?

Tags: r, shiny, hover, plotly, r-plotly

I have a plotly heatplot, which on hover triggers the plotting of another line chart. This is fairly time-intensive. This is why I would like to trigger the hover event only if the hover took longer than 2 seconds. Is there a way to do this in shiny/plotly ?

Here's the hover event:

```
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
event_data <- event_data("plotly_hover", source = "heatplot")
if (length(event_data)) {
  selectedDate <- event_data[["y"]]
  #draw Plot
  ggplot(myData[date==selectedDate], aes(y=y, x=x)) + geom_line()
}
})
```

Comment: why do you use the hover event? why not the select event? The latter seems easier to me

Comment: The select event has other (more important) functionality. The plot I'm triggering via hover is just an additional information for the user.

Comment: that explains stuff :D maybe you you can delay the reaction? like, e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174799/how-to-make-execution-pause-sleep-wait-for-x-seconds-in-r

Comment: I tried Sys.sleep(x), but sadly it seems to delay all other functions in shiny as well